# Verifying a prompt with a password and onclick go to a specific link javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
var i = prompt("Enter The Password:");
    if (i === "hawaiian tropical" || "Hawaiian Tropical") {
        onclick="location.href='';"
    }
```

there is the code. as you see, i am trying to make sure the password is 1 of the 2 and if they are, go to a specific link. But right now it is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused. The title and the body of the question each ask for two different things. If you want to go to a specific URL if the password is correct, then this would work:

```
var i = prompt("Enter The Password:");
if (i === "hawaiian tropical" || i === "Hawaiian Tropical") {
  window.location.href = '';
}
```

While if you want to go to a specific URL when the password is correct and a button is clicked, use this:

```js
var i = prompt("Enter The Password:");
if (i === "hawaiian tropical" || i === "Hawaiian Tropical") {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = window.location.replace('');
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Your condition will always be true.
replace  `i === "hawaiian tropical" || "Hawaiian Tropical"` by `i === "hawaiian tropical" || i === "Hawaiian Tropical"`

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You set `document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = ...` in the if statement, but you have to add the `onclick` listener before clicking on the button. I suggest you to get more information from the author of the question and fix the answer, because this piece of code may bring problems.

Comment: I edited the answer, using a different approach. Have a look.

Comment: Anyway, I believe, that it's still incorrect, but looks like you helped the author, so I think he will create a new question if there will be another problem. Thanks)

Comment: no, i don't need the button. Thanks though, the solution works